# SetText to Textview in Fragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, textview

I've read some related question about this before, but none of them I can understand.

I have files:

```
Nutrisi.java
Nutrisifragmenta.java
activity_nutrisi.xml
activity_nutrisi_fragment_a.xml
```

here the Nutrisi.java script

```
public class Nutrisi extends AppCompatActivity {

Nutrisitabadapter adapter_nutrisi;
TabLayout tab_nutrisi;
ViewPager view_nutrisi;
VideoView video_nutrisi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nutrisi);

    tab_nutrisi = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab_nutrisi);
    view_nutrisi = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_nutrisi);
    video_nutrisi = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_nutrisi);
    adapter_nutrisi = new Nutrisitabadapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter_nutrisi.addFragment(new Nutrisifragmenta(),"Nutrisi A");
    adapter_nutrisi.addFragment(new Nutrisib(),"Nutrisi B");

    view_nutrisi.setAdapter(adapter_nutrisi);
    tab_nutrisi.setupWithViewPager(view_nutrisi);

}
}
```

and here my Nutrisifragmenta.java script

```
public class Nutrisifragmenta extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_nutrisi_fragment_a, container, false);
}
}
```

Nutrisifragmenta have a layout, and this the layout, activity_nutrisi_fragment_a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="something"
        android:id="@+id/txt_nutrisi_a"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

how can I setText to txt_nutrisi_a (activity_nutrisi_fragment_a.xml) from Nutrisi.java Activity

Comment: I guess, the question is about to get a fragment from `ViewPager` and update some TextView of a `Fragment`. Is that what you are saying @Arif?

Comment: yes, it is.
I've finish, I found solution from several source, including this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

and my problem solved

Answer (score 0):

In Nutrisi.java

```
TextView mNutrisi;
```

onCreate:

```
mNutrisi = findViewById(R.id.txt_nutrisi_a);
mNutrisi.setText("Your Text");
```